# Attempt to display an image on a click of a button throws 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)'

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need a click of a save button to save an image currently on the input canvas and fetch and display another image on the output canvas. The save part works. The fetch and display part throws the 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)'.

Here is the save.js code:

```
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveImage);

function saveImage(){
    //Save image on the input canvas:
    var data = canvas.toDataURL();

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState ==4 && request.status ==200){ 
        var response = request.response.Text;
        document.getElementById('downloadframe').src = 'download.php?file='+response;
        }
    }
    request.open('POST', 'save.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send('img='+data);

    //Fetch and display output image:
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas_out");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("bla");
    ctx.drawImage(img, window.innerWidth/2, 0);
}
```

Canvas and image are defined in index.html like the following:

```
    <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block;" align="left">
         Bla-bla.
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_out" style="display: block;" align="right">
         Bla-bla.
    </canvas>
    <img id = "bla" src="bla.png" align="right">
    <script src="save.js"></script>
```

Not sure if that's relevant: I use php local server i.e. `php -S localhost:8000`

bla.png image is located in the same folder as the index.html file. Code works for the save part but doesn't for drawImage part - throws 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500'.

**UPDATE:**
If I change the image source to `<img id = "bla" src="http://localhost:8000/download.php?file=bla.png" align="right">` I receive the following errors in the console:
[image]

Comment: Could you please navigate with your browser to `http://localhost:8000/download.php?file=bla.png`? Does it return 500?

Comment: Have you verified that the download.php has no errors and that it is reachable in the same url path? It sounds like either the download.php file cannot be found in that path, or your server maybe failing to render it because it contains some errors.

Comment: If I change the link for the image according to GrafiCode advice I receive two errors, 1: 'Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
    at HTMLDivElement.saveImage' and 2: 500 again.

Comment: What is the error on your server and how is the code looking alike where it's thrown?

Comment: How do I check that download.php is reachable on that path?

Comment: You have a server error. You need to tell us what the server error is. You are showing how the UI crashes due to the server error, but that's the symptom, not the illness.

Comment: Hang on a minute please, I am trying to find out how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, was jogging in the meantime. You will just need to take a look at the server logs.